# How do I give other collaborators permission to also add other collaborators on parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm currently a collaborator on a parse.com project, and I am the only collaborator working on the project who has the ability to add other collaborators. How do I give permission to other collaborators to also add other collaborators? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Collaborators can only be added or removed by the app owner.

Comment: Have you completely disabled the ability to add collaborators? I am the project owner and I find myself unable to add a colleague. Using the new dashboard there is no button or call to action after adding his email, and using the old dashboard it says Parse account not found even though I am 100% certain the account exists. He is sitting next to me logged in to his Parse account with the email address I enter.

Comment: The functionality should still be there. In the New Dashboard, you will only see the "Add" button show up if the email matches an actual Parse account. If you're sure that the email is absolutely correct, can you let us know what email address of the account you're trying to add as a collab?

Comment: It turned there was an invisible leading space from the copy and paste and the input isn't trimmed. Thanks for the quick response :)